# How to select certain collectors and certain systemd services inside node exporter config file?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I have a prometheus instance which scrapes linux targets. Linux hosts has node exporter as a systemd service in running state. I can select collectors or which systemd services to monitor inside /etc/systemd/system/node_exporter.service file at ExecStart row like this:

ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node_exporter --web.config.file="/etc/node_exporter/config.yml" --collector.systemd --collector.systemd.unit-include="(promtail|node_exporter|ssh|chrony)\.service"

In windows targets I select which collectors to use inside node_exporter registry config like:

"C:\Program Files\windows_exporter\windows_exporter.exe" --web.config.file="C:\Program Files\windows_exporter\config.yml" --log.file eventlog --collectors.enabled="cpu,cpu_info,cs,iis,logical_disk,logon,memory,net,os,process,remote_fx,scheduled_task,service,system,tcp,time,thermalzone"

In windows systems when i select service collector it collects all services on that windows host.

What I want to do is select all collectors that I want to use and select all services that I want to monitor inside a config file both for linux and windows. I think I googled enough before asking here but could not solve how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out with a fresh mind this morning. I am writing down how I somehow solved my own problem.

I created 2 config files for windows exporter inside C:\Program Files\windows_exporter path where executable is also located. 1 file is config.yml and the other one is web-config.yml. I modified node_exporter service registry as follows:

"C:\Program Files\windows_exporter\windows_exporter.exe" --web.config.file="C:\Program Files\windows_exporter\web-config.yml"  --config.file="C:\Program Files\windows_exporter\config.yml" --log.file eventlog"

web-config.yml content:

```
basic_auth_users:
  username: "password_hash"
```

config.yml content:

```
collectors:   enabled: cpu,cpu_info,cs,iis,logical_disk,logon,memory,net,os,process,remote_fx,scheduled_task,service,system,tcp,time,thermalzone collector:   service:
    services-where: "Name='windows_exporter' OR Name='rpcss' OR Name='Netlogon' OR Name='W32Time' OR Name='EventLog'"
```

I restarted windows_exporter service and it is all done.